# Windows 8 Hyper-V Client Backup Solution

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am planning to create a server environment consisting of 1 hardware pc running Windows 8.
On that Windows 8 machine I run 2 VM server one running linux the other is running windows 7. Is there a software backup solution to be able to backup on the fly taking snapshots and backups. Something 3rd party I can install and stop worrying about.

I know that I can shutdown the machine and copy the file. But one server is a mail server and that's not possible to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Which platform, you are planning to run VMs on top of?

Comment: Windows 8? Have you tried: http://hypervbackup.codeplex.com/. There are small small issues. You can also try Unitrends (free for 2 VMs). You can collaborate PowerShell with Windows built in backup to take snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was in the same situation than you without finding any satisfying solution, I wrote PowerShell script to do the job.

I published it to [Github: Windows8.Hyper-V.Backup](https://github.com/stevebeauge/Windows8.Hyper-V.Backup).

The script has hardcoded path and should be enhanced, but it works.

Basically, the script rely on the Windows built-in Shadow Services to be able to copy a file locked by another executable (Hyper-V service in this case).